# jQuery div Slide in on scrolldown, slide out on scrollup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, jquery-animate

This lets me slide the `#contact` div in, but when I scroll up it doesn't slide back out.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#scrolltop').fadeIn();
        $('#contact').animate({
            right: "0px"
        }, 500 );
    } else {
        $('#scrolltop').fadeOut();
        $('#contact').animate({
           right: "-115px"
        }, 500 );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scroll event is fired many times when a user scrolls, and with your code, the animate function is called many times in quick succession which seems to be causing problems. I would recommend adding a flag to determine if you have already called animate. This code worked for me:

```
var animated = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    if(!animated){
        $('#scrolltop').fadeIn();
        $('#contact').animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500 );
        animated = true;
    }
} else if(animated){
    $('#scrolltop').fadeOut();
    $('#contact').animate({
       left: -115
    }, 500 );
    animated = false;
}
```

EDIT:

To solve the problem that multiple animate calls are made repeatedly when the user scrolls up and down quickly, I would additionally keep track of whether the element is currently animating, like this:

```
    var animated = false;
    var animating = false;
    $(window).scroll(scroll);

    function scroll(){
        if(!animating) {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    if(!animated){
                    animating = true;
                        $('#scrolltop').fadeIn();
                        $('#contact').animate({
                                left: 0
                        }, {"duration":500,"complete":complete});
                        animated = true;
                    }
            } else if(animated){
                animating = true;
                    $('#scrolltop').fadeOut();
                    $('#contact').animate({
                        left: -115
                    }, {"duration":500,"complete":complete} );
                    animated = false;
            }
        }
    }

    function complete(){
        animating = false;
        scroll();
    }
```

In this code, `animated` shows whether the element has slid in or out of the screen, whereas `animating` shows whether an animation (either in or out) is currently being used. I would recommend doing this rather than try and use timeouts.

Comment: Thanks, I also realized I need a timeout function to stop this from getting annoying and sliding back and forth. I couldn't really wrap my head around it. Do you know how I could add that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sliding back and forth'? The `#contact` element is set to slide in at a certain point, and slide back out when you scroll back up. Is that not what you want to happen?

Comment: Yes, I need it to slide in and out, but if someone scrolls up and down quickly a few times, the '#contact' also slides left and right just as many times, so it keeps sliding in and out even after someone has stopped scrolling. I need it to be limited in terms of how many times it's going to slide in and out for a set amount of time. For example slide in only once every 2 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but it's still buggy...if I scroll down and up quickly, it doesn't slide back in. Then it starts doing the animation backwards. I'm not sure what approach you're using but from what I've seen this is done with bind and setTimeout. I just don't know how to put it all together.

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug in my code but it should be fixed now. If this still doesn't work I can try something with `setTimeout` but it really shouldn't be necessary

Comment: Awesome bud, thumbs up.